# App works on some phones and not on others

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, manifest

The app I have been working on for quite some time now seems to work on my phone, but when I install it on other phones it either shows up properly, show up partially, or it won't open at all for some reason. I have checked the manifest:

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.Checkbox">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.InputActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.ReviewActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Note that API level on my phone is 27, it works, I have tried on other Android 8 phones, on some it works, on some it works partially (see picture below, a button is missing), and on some phones the app opens, is blank for a second or two and then closes.

**What you should normally have on the first activity:**

[image]

**What is on a Huawei P9 (see the missing button):**

[image]

And on other phones the app installs but simply won't show the first activity, and will close in a few seconds with no crash.

Here is the **XML** code for first activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_10">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_mlarge">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_middle"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/spacing_mlarge">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/input_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:text="Bienvenue sur MBTouch!"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/green_500"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Numéro d'identification:"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_identif"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_600"
                android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date de naissance (jj/mm/aaaa):"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_naiss"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="date"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_600"
                android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Poids (kg.g) (ex: 84.2):"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_poids"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_600"
                android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Taille (m.cm) (ex: 1.82):"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_taille"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:maxLength="50"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textColor="@color/blue_600"
                android:theme="@style/EditText.Grey" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/input_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:onClick="onContinue"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"
                android:text="Commencer"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mlarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Application conçue par S.C. iNeedHelp S.R.L."
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="On vous attend sur https://ineedhelp.be/ !"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:textColor="@color/grey_40" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_mlarge"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:src="@drawable/ineedhelp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_large" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the **Java** for the first activity:

public class InputActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);
}

public void onContinue(View v){
    EditText i = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_identif);
    EditText d = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_naiss);
    EditText p = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_poids);
    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_taille);

    String ident = i.getText().toString();
    String date = d.getText().toString();
    String poids = p.getText().toString();
    String taille = t.getText().toString();

    if (ident.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Le numéro d'identification ne peut pas être vide!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (!isValidDate(date)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Veuillez introduire une date au format JJ/MM/AAAA (ex: 12/10/1975).",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if(!isValidDouble(poids)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Veuillez introduire un nombre (avec un point, pas de virgule) pour le poids (ex: 75.3).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if(!isValidDouble(taille)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Veuillez introduire un nombre (avec un point, pas de virgule) pour la taille (ex: 1.85).",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Double tl = Double.parseDouble(taille.trim());
                    Double po = Double.parseDouble(poids.trim());
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Checkbox.class);
                    mIntent.putExtra("identification", ident);
                    mIntent.putExtra("date", date);
                    mIntent.putExtra("poids", po.toString());
                    mIntent.putExtra("taille", tl.toString());
                    Double bmi = (po / (tl*tl));
                    mIntent.putExtra("bmi", bmi.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"BMI: " + bmi.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

public boolean isValidDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        df.parse(dateString);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isValidDouble(String number) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(number.trim());
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

**Gradle**:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.ineedhelp.patientquiz"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // google support library ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0'

    // third party dependencies -------------------------------------------------------------------
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'                  // ripple effect
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'             // image loader
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.0'         // date & time picker
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'          // circle image view
    compile 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.8'         // material chip
    compile 'com.hootsuite.android:nachos:1.1.1'                // material chips

    testCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
}
```

Do you think you know what could cause this? I sign the APKs with Level1 and Level2 signature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is missing on some phones because for some phones it's impossible to find `android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"` so your button isn't missing, it's just invisible. To check this you should change `android:textColor` of button. Then check that your drawable resourse `"@drawable/btn_rounded_primary"` is on the correct dirrectory.
I need more information to understand, why does your app crash on some phones. Could you write me API level of those phones?

Comment: Yes, I have removed that line and left the basic android button and now it works on all phones. Thanks a lot. The phones that failed were Android 6.0

Comment: Have you tried to run app on those phones on debug mode and look for error description?

Comment: I don't have physical access to these phones unfortunately, I had to try them via some friends

Answer (score 0):

check your gradle file or project structure. 
may be your API version is higher than your destination device.
select lower API would solve this problem

Comment: Well, in Gradle it's set on SDK 25, minimum 21, and before I made some design changes the app worked on all phones. I have made these design changes (in XML file), and now it works only sometimes for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `sdk` versions of those phones on which the app is not working. The min sdk version of your app is 21, phones running sdk versions below 21 won't support the app.

Comment: Obviously, but why is the button missing on the main activity on a Huawei P9 then? Android 7.1, same as my Samsung S5 RR. It works great on a OnePlus 5T

Answer (score 0):

All right, so I figured out what was wrong, apparently some phones don't like the option `android:background` on buttons, I have removed that and now it seems to work properly.